# Why the script doesn't work on by line which is I wrote?

Tags: lua

I'm writing code on the byline but it does not work that it works like an Asynchronous program.

the code :

```
   function kontrol()
      local y = 0
      RegisterNetEvent("example")
      AddEventHandler("example", function(source,sayi)
         local x = source
         y = x
         
      end)
       return y 
 end
```

the function returns 0 although y = x how can I make this code to return the value of x ?

Answer (score 1):

Initially y is zero, so you should wait asynchronically before asking for the value.

```
function kontrol()
   local y = 0
   RegisterNetEvent("example")
   AddEventHandler("example", function(source,sayi)
      local x = source
      y = x
   end)
   return function() return y end
end

local get_y = kontrol()
-- wait a bit until event happened
local y = get_y()
-- now you have y
```

Or you may pass a function for doing something with y when it is ready.

```
function kontrol(f)
   local y = 0
   RegisterNetEvent("example")
   AddEventHandler("example", function(source,sayi)
      local x = source
      y = x
      f(y)
   end)
end

kontrol(
   function(y)
      -- do something with y here
      print(y) 
   end)
```